# Displaying text with JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple counter but the window that appears doesn't show anything at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I feel like it has something to do with the output String not properly updating. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Can only be wrong after all.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class main {

public static int counter = 0;
public static int end = 100;
public static String output;

public static void main (String[] args){
    window();
}
public static void window(){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(output, JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setAlignmentX(0);
    label.setAlignmentY(0);

    JFrame window = new JFrame("");
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(500,500);
    window.add(label);
}

public static void counter(String counter1) throws InterruptedException{

    Random rand = new Random();

    int start = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < end; i++){
        int random = rand.nextInt(60) + 1;
        start ++;

        if (start != 0){

            for(int z =0; z <= random; z++){
                counter ++;
                System.out.print(counter);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
        start = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: call `setvisible `after add lable.and u haven't even call counter method.

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character.

Comment: `doesn't show anything ` what do u expect to appear? a empty lable ?

Comment: Three thingies, call to `setVisible(...)` should be the last line, after adding everythingy on the top level container, as already stated. Secondly, the call to `Thread.sleep (...)` is another culprit, since it is blocking. Lastly, where is the `Event Dispatcher Thread`, the most important thingy, while doing `Swing` based programming. Will the `start` ever be `0`. You assigning value `0` to it, at the end of the loop and then incrementing it by `1`

Comment: I'm still new to this so I apologise if there is some confusion about all this. Thank you for all of your input however, it has been very useful.

Comment: @masteryupa: Just let us know, what exactly you trying to achieve, we will simply guide you on that track, you using some variables in your code, for nothing, so the actual need is not clear. Just what needs to be done, clarify that part a bit more

Answer (score 0):

The String output equals null.

You did never say to Java, this String, equals "bread", for example.
But Java needs this information, otherwise it is nothing.

If you are typing **before** the creation of the JLabel,

```
output = "Bread";
```

It should display Bread on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things in order to make this work:

- Create the JLabel with some specific text like "It works" and get it to display properly. This may require calling pack() and setVisible(true) after adding JLabel to the JFrame.
- Then you need to start the counting process. Currently it does not look like that method is getting called.
- Finally you need to update the JLabel with new text label.setText(String.valueOf(count).